# What is the best way to swap values in Python pandas DataFrame to clean up the data

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame where the column 'Name' has some errors in it.  I have created a dictionary with the incorrect spellings at the key and the values as the correct spelling.  What is the best way to replace the the incorrect spellings with the correct spellings?  This is what I did.

```
for incorrect, correct in incorrect_to_correct.items():
    mask = s_df['Name'] == incorrect
    s_df.loc[mask, 'Name'] = correct
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  I was told that generally if you are using a for loop with pandas that you should rethink what you are doing?  Is there a better way to clean up the data?  Is this dictionary method "wrong"?  I am new to pandas and any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict`:

```
df.Name = df.Name.replace(incorrect_to_correct)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ["john","mary","jon", "mar"]})
print (df)
   Name
0  john
1  mary
2   jon
3   mar

incorrect_to_correct = {'jon':'john', 'mar':'mary'}

df.Name = df.Name.replace(incorrect_to_correct)
print (df)
   Name
0  john
1  mary
2  john
3  mary
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is this generally the way people would do it or is their a better approach?

Comment: I think this is generally the way people would do it. Thank you for accepting!

Comment: @jezrael's approach is the best way to accomplish what you need. Using a dictionary with `map` is an alternative. Note, however, that you have to include ALL of the strings (including the correct ones) to avoid missing values with the `map` approach. Sometimes that suits a use-case better than `replace`. But not here.